# Where is Key Id in flutter IOS for Firebase AppCheck

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-app-check

When it comes to the android integration, I understand entirely but IOS is out of my field. I recall setting up firebase auth with ios and it required a bundle ID. However, I don't believe these are the same as the Key Id can only be 10 characters long. As to the Team ID and private key file, I don't know where to find those either. I looked throughout the runner files in my Flutter project. Am I supposed to be using a MacBook for these types of things?
[image]

Comment: You'll need to create a key on your apple developer account: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devc3cc013b7. Once created, you can retrieve the Key ID: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev646934554

Answer (score 0):

[Enable App Check with DeviceCheck on Apple platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider)

> On the Apple developer site, [create a DeviceCheck private key](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devc3cc013b7).

Follow the instructions to create and download a private key with DeviceCheck enabled. Key Id refers to the id of a private key. Team Id is also found from Apple developer site.